# meaning of U and V as in getU()

Tags: java, libgdx

I inspected docs for TextureRegion class. I am unsure of the meaning `getU(), setU(), getV(),setV(),getU2(),setU2()...`methods. What do they do and in what scenarios are useful to the programmer. Back in the days I was creating UV maps for 3d objects. Are those the UV's related to 3D graphics?  This is the link to it: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#setU-float-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U and V are standard names for texture coordinates, much like X and Y are standard names for 2D plots.

They are used in 3D graphics when textures are mapped to a 2D surface. Typically, U and V each have values from 0.0 to 1.0. For example, when mapping a texture to a square surface, one typically specifies each corner of the texture in pixel coordinates and matches each corner to either 0,0 or 0,1 or 1,1 or 1,0 in UV coordinates.

But, you can do much more with how you map these coordinates. You can rotate, flip and stretch a texture on a surface. If you change the UV coordinates over time, you will achieve the effect of animating the texture over the surface.

Answer (score 4):

UV is coordinates of sample (pixel) in 2d texture. UVW - same but for 3d texture.

I suppose in case of this class, it allows to set region that will be used, instead of full texture. It is often done when you need a lot of small textures - since most cards don't support large amount of textures loaded (for example - mobile chip holds around 4-32, desktop - 128-512) they packed in single texture image and then selected by UV coordinates range that defines rectangular zone.

`SetU` and `SetV` is for upper left corner, `setU2` and `setV2` for bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. i'm stilla little confused. Aren't texture atlases used for packing smaller images in a larger one? Why having the UV's then?

Comment: UV allows to select single texture from atlas, which in adapter represented by a single texture. For example, you have an atlas with 4 pics of same size, then to use picture 1, which in left top corner, you use only range from 0 to 0.5 for U and V. If you don't limit them, then video adapter will use entire texture - which means you get a mix from 4 pictures instead on one.